# ToolStripStatusLabel delay message

Tags: c#, time, statusbar, toolstripstatuslabel

I have a brief question.

In my program I want to use a ToolStripStateLabel to display some info to the user. Comming from c++ and QT I don't quite understand the .net variant of this controll. Because I want to show the user a message for a certain ammount of time I.E 3000ms. or 3 seconds but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. So, is it even possible and, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to implement `Timer` to do that.

```
private void InitTimer()
{
  var myTimer = new Timer();
  myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);

  // Sets the timer interval to 3 seconds.
  myTimer.Interval = 3000;
  myTimer.Start();
}

private static void TimerEventProcessor(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ToolStripStatusLabel.Visible = false;
  (sender as Timer).Stop();
}
```